# Sass - Target an ID restrict certain styles if it has matching class then add other styles set by class

Tags: html, css, sass

## Question

I need to target a `<section>` with a specific ID that will show up once in every page. But each will have a unique class. Some of the styles for the section will not apply if that class is added dynamically. Trying to figure out how to best nest the styling using Sass.

#### Code

### Demo

Here is a demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/pEkoEB).
Because it has the class of `.soldout`, the background should be grey not red.

[image]

#### HTML

```
<section id="featured-product" class="soldout">
  <h1>This car is no longer avaiable</h1>
  <img src="https://img.gta5-mods.com/q95/images/2013-lamborghini-veneno-hq-digitaldials/bb4811-venenomain.jpg">
</section>
```

#### SCSS

```
#featured-product {
  /* these styles always apply */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-align:center;


  /* These classes should not apply if the section has a class of .soldout */
  background: #FC332E;
  padding: 25px 30px 45px;

  & .soldout {
    /* These styles only apply when the element has matching ID and this class added in*/
    background: #BDBEBA;
    padding: 25px;
  }
  img { width: 400px; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between & and .soldout {

```
&.soldout {
```

The way you had it, was you were looking for .soldout WITHIN #featured-product because you had the space.

You weren't looking for #featured-product WITH the class of .soldout

Comment: ok good point, that takes care to add styles in `.soldout` but if there a way to not add other styles listed that do not apply, like nest a `:not(.soldout)` above it?

Comment: Exactly, but since you're overwriting those properties, it's technically not necessary, but you'd want to do &:not(.soldout){ //Properties go here }